# building identity server - why so few project after mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have followed the instructions [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Building+from+Source) for building IS 4.6.0, in summary:

1. SVN Checkout from: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06
2. Commented out APIMGT in $CARBON_SRC/product-releases/chunk-06/products/pom.xml
3. Commented out SS in $CARBON_SRC/product-releases/chunk-06/products/pom.xml
4. Run mvn `clean install` on $CARBON_SRC/product-releases/chunk-06/products/pom.xml
5. Run mvn `eclipse:eclipse` on $CARBON_SRC/product-releases/chunk-06/products/pom.xml

*NOTE: I scripted these steps rather than manually run them. The bash script is [here](https://github.com/snowch/carbon-products-development-environment/blob/0b22353b37bbfe483fbc2e6e008a39f85d0547df/scripts/developer_setup.sh).*

However, when I try to import the projects into eclipse, I only have the following projects as shown in the picture below.

**Question**: Does the number of projects imported look right?  I was expecting to see a lot more imported projects.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to import the all the source of the WSO2 Identity Server in to eclipse? I guess it is not much easy.  Because WSO2 Identity Server is only an one product in Carbon platform. There are many components that help to build this product.. If you just see the source inside the [svn](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/products/) that you tried. You may not find much java source code there. Java source of the actual components that builds the product, can found at under the component [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/components/).

Carbon platform consists of many features (set of OSGI component). As an example, XACML (we said it as "entitlement" ) is an one feature of WSO2 Carbon platform and it is shipped with WSO2 Identity Server. Like that there are several feature such as SSO, OAuth, WS-Trust and many more... that are shipped with Identity Server. Therefore; Say, if you are only interesting in XACML feature, you can look in to the XACML feature's source code. XACML feature is a set of four OSGI components as follows...

- org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement -> This is the core component.
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui  --> This contains the management console UI that can be seen once you login to the server.
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.common --> This contains some common functions of both core and UI
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub --> This contains auto generated stub class. This helps UI component to call the backend services.

You can search under that "components/identity/" in chuck 06,  you would be able to find the source of these components.

Like that, you can find the source of the feature that you are interested. We can not find the WSO2 Identity Sever's product source from one place. However most of the source are under /platform/components/identity.

I guess this would help you to get some understand.

Comment: Hi Asela, I would like to setup a development environment that would allow a complete newbie to start getting familiar with all the IS code. I don't know if this goal is too big - I imagine it takes a new wso2 employee many months before they understand the structure of a product like WSO2 IS?

Comment: It is difficult to familiar with all the Identity Server source in few days.. What I recommended it that; please find an interesting feature that you like in the Identity Server (such as XACML. OAuth or what ever). And study the source of it. Because all these feature has been build on a one platform... if you studied one feature.. It is easy to go with others as well...  Yes.. actually mostly the java developers are also experts (in code level) in one or few features. But they have the overall idea what is happening,  which is important to dig into any other feature easily